# Agregar DLLs a ejecutable python pyinstaller

Tags: python, xpath, pyinstaller

cree un ejectuable con pyinstaller para que lo use otra persona y cunado lo ejecuta le informa que le faltan DLLs y quisiera saber como incluirlos en el programa para que funcione.

```
C:\Users\Juan\Desktop>"Completa tramite"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Completa tramite.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
[5612] Failed to execute script Completa tramite
```

Este error se presenta en un maquina virtual que no tiene python instalado, como en la que se va a estar ejecutando el programa en cuestion.

Lei por ahi que hay que especificar la ruta a donde estan almacenados los DLLs o el PATH el Python, pero la verdad es que es un tema que nunca termine de entender del todo bien y no encuentro respuestas bien explicadas al respecto, todas asumen conocimientos en cuanto al PATH o de donde se encuentran los DLLs que yo no tengo.

`.spec`

```
`.spec` file
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Completa tramite.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\PINOCHO\\Desktop\\COVID\\Plataformas'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Completa tramite',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Si alguno me ayuda se lo agradeceria muchisimo.
Saludos

Comment: Que estás intentando hacer?

Comment: podrías añadir el archivo `<modulo>.spec` que se genera al ejecutar pyinstaller? parece que no está leyendo correctamente tus imports... adicionalmente, qué version de `pandas` estás usando? encontré otra pregunta en SO que dice que se le solucionó instalando pandas 1.0.1

Comment: Acabo de recordar que hace poco instale python 3.8 y que tuve que instalar algunos paquetes de nuevo porque me lo ejecutaba por defecto.
Hoy por hoy tengo las dos versiones 3.8 y 3.7, con ambas tengo todas las librerias instaladas como para que el programa se ejecute con las 2 versionses y la version de pandas es la 1.0.5 en ambas versiones de python@DannyTalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Posible solución 1

Modifica el campo `binaries` con el path a los DLLs faltantes

```
a = Analysis(['Completa tramite.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\PINOCHO\\Desktop\\COVID\\Plataformas'],
             binaries=[('C:\\path\\al\\DLL\\de\\pandas.dll', 'dlls') ],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Ahora en lugar de poner `pyinstaller modulo.py` lo llamas `pyinstaller modulo.spec`, porque si llamas directamente al archivo .py te va a generar un nuevo spec, y queremos usar el spec modificado.

### Posible solución 2

Hay otra solución que encontré en SO, intentar instalar pandas version 1.0.1

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

### Posible solución 3

Leyendo [issues de github](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4780), incluso de otros paquetes, uno de los contribuidores de `scikit-image` dice:

> Creo que sólo es un problema con la distribución de Python.org, que
> sólo incluye la DLL mínima de tiempo de ejecución en C, no en C++ u
> OpenMP.

Por lo que también podría ser una fuente de error el que no tengas actualizadas las librerías de C++

Para Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Reinstale la version de pandas 1.0.1 y tambien modifique el `.spec` de la siguiente manera:
`binaries=[('C:\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\_libs\\window\\concrt140.dll', '.'), ('C:\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\_libs\\window\\msvcp140.dll', '.')]`
pero sigue reportando los mismo errores de dlls @DannyTallent

Comment: A ver, actualiza tu `vc_redist` ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Parece que hay bastante gente con este mismo problema... https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32857

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando Pandas==1.0.1 se soluciona, dado que los DLLs que faltan son muchos como para correr en una VM.

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más especifico en la solución? Esta respuesta le puede servir a otros usuarios con el mismo problema, es necesario que aclares la solución y des una mejor explicación, de lo contrario se tomará como respuesta de baja calidad.